# Change the delimiter character in csv exports in Wordpress (Caldera Forms)

Tags: wordpress, csv, hook

I have created a form in Wordpress using Caldera Forms. When trying to export all posts into a CSV file I run into problems, because the delimiter used in Caldera Forms is a comma. Lots of fields in the form are text fields where users can and will use commas. So when I try to import the CSV file into MS Excel these extra commas are interpreted as separators.

So, I look in Caldera Forms and there is no way to just change the delimiter character. I then try to google out a hook to change it by implementing it in the module Code Snippets. I can't find such a snippet though, so my last resort is to ask if anyone can point me in the right direction here.

I have checked that the csv document is in UTF8 format, which is also what I choose when importing it into Excel (using the data function). So the problem shouldn't be an encoding problem, just too many commas...

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is very loose and doesn't have a single, global spec. The generally accepted practice however is to enclose that field in quotation marks:

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  post_title  |    post_content     |      post_date      | post_type |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| "Some Title" | "This, Is, Content" | 2020-12-02 01:02:02 | post      |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

So the following will be parsed correctly, since it escapes the commas:

```
"Some Title","This, Is, Content",2020-12-02 01:02:02,post,
"Another Title","More, Content",2020-12-02 01:03:03,page,
```

If that's not an option in Caldera Forms, you'll either need to do it yourself, or reach out to the developers and ask them to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found a filter snippet that transforms the file to a tab separated file, which worked fine. Your solution works also though, so that was the right answer to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi ToJo_195. Can you share the snipped you used please?